# Are hashtags recommended for Facebook?

Tags: seo, facebook

Are `hashtags` recommended for facebook posts ? I have seen less use of hash tags by major brands in their business pages but the *hash tag* trend confuses me. Are they recommended in terms of SEO or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

Personaly I think the hashtags are not very usefull. If you use them, use 1, max 2 of them.

I don't know the SEO value of the hashtags, but I know it's considered "A Twitter Thing", and a lot of FB users get ennoyed by the hashtags "If I wanted those, I'd go to Twitter".

I've never seen anyone actually searching something based on a hashtag. The results aren't too exciting, because FB has (ironicly) a more private climate, messages are not accessable to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

There is minimal SEO value but they do help your audience find your content based on relevant hashtags for topics that people are interested in. Overdoing the hashtags however appears to [result in less engagement](http://mashable.com/2014/03/21/facebook-hashtags-brands/) so worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I see hashtags for more or less value on Twitter than Facebook. Facebook does use them now, but I see people using them for jokes and *just to be cool*.

SEO value may be small on Facebook, but they could help to some sense for all we know, but Facebook does not use them like Facebook does sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtag in Facebook are not effective like Google+ & Twitter. Find out details here - http://socialtimes.com/facebook-hashtags-arent-effective-study-says_b138816